# Drupal 7 client side validation on registration form?

Tags: forms, validation, drupal, drupal-7

I have a pretty complex registration form.. it has about 40 fields (go ahead and laugh, the client wants it that way, argh).

Some of the fields are hidden/shown based on the value of other fields.

The problem with using Drupal built in "required" field is that fields that are not displayed are still tagged as required. Reason being the Drupal validation is done server side.

I need to do client side validation because of the way some fields are hidden/shown.

Is this even possible? If so, how should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, there is an #ajax property you can use for this, you are going to have to go quite deep into the form api to achieve this.

http://drupal.org/node/1043838

This not going to be easy, it is one of the most challenging aspects. I think a bit of training would help

I would look at maybe getting a membership for a month to drupalize me or https://buildamodule.com

I have only used Druplaize me as it has more d6 stuff but buildamodule.com is very well priced at $29usd a month. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this describes the use of the new feature #state in the FAPI.  You can read about that here: http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [the clientside_validation module](http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation), it can handle 'hidden' fields. But normally Drupal validate should respect the #required in combination with #states.